# How do I change the append title value from a template?

Tags: seo, plugin-sproutseo

There used to be something like `appendTitleValue` that could be overwritten from a template. This seems to be gone in the last major release.

Any chance to get that back or am I missing something here? It’s quite an important feature as it has direct impact on good, site specific titles generating SEO value.

Any hint is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this was a [setting](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/docs/craft-v2/seo/global-metadata.html#customization) in the [Sprout SEO Plugin for Craft 2](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/docs/craft-v2/), as a quick [Google search for 'craft appendTitleValue'](https://www.google.com/search?q=craft%20appendTitleValue) will tell you. Apparently, it has been removed in the version of the plugin for Craft 3.

I can't speak to the developer's motivation, but a likely explanation is that this is something you can and should handle in your templates. If you're not using the Sprout SEO plugin right now, you can just include the site name (or whatever you want) in your template:

```twig
<title>{{ entry.title }} | {{ currentSite.name }}</title>
```

If you are using the Sprout SEO plugin, checkout the documentation on [template overrides](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/docs/seo/template-overrides.html#templating) for specific meta fields. The following code should accomplish roughly the same thing:

```twig
{% do craft.sproutSeo.meta({
    title: "#{entry.title} | #{currentSite.name}",
}) %}
```

Comment: The `do craft.sproutSeo.meta` tag gives the flexibility to append a title value from different points in the Twig template being loaded, if you need to customize things in the templates. In Sprout SEO's Globals->Customization settings there are three related settings: `Character used between Title segments`, `Append value to all Meta Titles`, and `Display Append Meta Title Value on Homepage`